# sf::Image::loadFromMemory read access violation

Tags: c++, sfml

so what im trying to do is take a screenshot from the entire screen(not only from sfml window) and saving it to memory to then save to a file (i am trying to just save to memory but to debug i am saving) and it gives me the error at the title (i am only using 1 file for a while)

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>

#undef IS_USING_TEXT

void* screenCapturePart() {
HDC hdcSource = GetDC(nullptr);
HDC hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSource);

int capX = GetDeviceCaps(hdcSource, HORZRES);
int capY = GetDeviceCaps(hdcSource, VERTRES);

HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSource, 1920, 1080);
HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmap);

BitBlt(hdcMemory, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, hdcSource, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmapOld);

return hBitmap;
}

int WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, 
_In_ int nShowCmd)
{
#ifdef IS_USING_TEXT
static auto defFont = new sf::Font;
defFont->loadFromFile("Roboto-Regular.ttf");
#endif // IS_USING_TEXT

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800u, 800u), "SFML", sf::Style::Close);
window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
sf::Event evnt;

sf::Image screenshot;
screenshot.loadFromMemory(screenCapturePart(), (size_t)1920 * 1080 * sizeof(sf::Color));

if (screenshot.saveToFile("z.bmp"))
    window.close();

while (window.isOpen())
{
    

    ProcessEvents(window, evnt);
    window.clear();
    
    window.display();
}

#ifdef IS_USING_TEXT
delete defFont;
#endif // IS_USING_TEXT
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This cannot work. As the documentation says 'Load the image from a file in memory.' You have an HBITMAP, that is not the same format as BMP file.

Comment: A quick google and I found [this](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/527353/load-an-hbitmap-into-sfml-sf-image-container), does what you are asking for.

Comment: isnt bmp the short for bitmap?

Comment: BMP file is a specific file format, it is not the same as the in memory format used by the Windows API (which is undocumented as far as I can tell). Anyway see the link I posted it shows how to do what you want.

Comment: either i am creating the wrong bitmap or it doesnt work, if it is the first option(probably) than i dont know how to get the bitmap from the screen but the link is good, thanks